# How can I make my dish less sour?

Tags: chicken, sauce, flavor, grilling, acidity

I use peri peri sauce for grilling chicken, but it's coming out to be too sour. How can I neutralize the sauce?

Comment: Use a recipe with less acid (typically lemon juice in the peri peri recipes I just googled), or reduce the acid in your current recipe.

Answer (score 7):

There is really no way to reduce the acidity in a marinade or sauce without creating undesirable flavor compounds. Adding a base would neutralize the acid but would also produce salts which don't taste so good.

If you are making a marinade then simply add less acid to it, however if you are using bottled sauce then you have a few options to deal with the excess acidity:

- Add some water: thin the mix out, and you will reduce the acidity. You will reduce the overall level of flavor but at least it won't make the chicken too vinegary
- Marinade using less sauce: Less sauce = less acidity
- Marinade for less time: this will mean less acidity, but less penetration of the flavors into the chicken
- Add some sweetener: this will not reduce the acidity but will balance it out

If it were me I'd combine some of the above, I'd add some sugar and maybe a bit of water until it's a bit weaker.

Comment: "Adding a base would neutralize the acid but would also produce salts which don't taste so good." ... in a sauce with strong other flavors, you might just get away with it - try with a small side batch :)

Answer (score 0):

Try marinading longer (e.g. overnight in fridge). The acid will be neutralized by the amino acids from the chicken and will also help tenderize the meat.